# Why does my subpanel have 4 wires feeding into the lugs?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

[image: Sub-panel for pool equipment]

Background: This is a sub-panel for my pool equipment (filter pump, cleaner pump, and pool light). The wires coming from the main panel come in through the bottom, and the wires going out the left side go to the timer box for the pumps. Note that the ground and neutral wires are bonded on the same bus. My understanding is that this was allowed under old code, so it's grandfathered in. I really have no other way to handle this because I can't easily run a fourth wire.

Question: Can you explain the wires coming from the main panel into the sun-panel? There are two black wires going into each of two lugs, and then two bare wires going to the ground bus. All of this is coming from a double-pole 60A breaker in the main panel.

Adding some more info...

[image: Pool Timer Box]

This is the pool timer box to the left of the sub-panel.  Yes, both pumps are 240V as far as I can tell.  The 120V circuit goes down into the GFCI outlet, and back out and over to a regular toggle light switch and the pool light.  I don't know how all of this passed the home inspection before I bought the house a few years ago, but it has all been working fine.

[image: main panel]

This is my main panel.  The sub-panel for the pool equipment is hooked up to the double-pole 60A breaker.  No sign of the aluminum wire anywhere, and there is no other sub-panel anywhere on my property.  My main panel was put in when I bought the house, and it replaced a main panel and a sub-panel right next to it.  I suspect that things got a little screwy as a result of that.

The reason that all of this came up was that I wanted to add a couple of regular 120V z-wave switches for the pool light and the filter pump.  The booster pump is no longer in use.  I thought I was going to need a 240V contactor in conjunction with one of the z-wave switches for the 240V filter pump, but now it sounds like this whole setup is screwed up.

Adding a couple more pictures for clarity...

[image: Meter box]

The conduit coming out of the top of the meter box goes up through the roof.  That's where the main service line from the pole comes in.  The conduit coming out of the bottom of the meter box (I believe) goes to the pool pump panel.  The conduit looks to be 2 inches in diameter.  Note that my main panel is on the other side of the wall from the meter box.  The transfer switch for my generator is on the let.  Don't mind the AT&T box on top of the meter box.

[image: Pool pump panel and timer box]

This is the sub-panel attached to a concrete fence at the back of my property.  It feeds into the Intermatic timer box to the left.  The conduit going into the bottom of the sub-panel is where the feeder wires are coming from.  The two lines coming out of the bottom of the timer box go to the two pumps.  The conduit coming of out the left side of the timer box goes to a GFCI outlet and switch for the pool light.  You may have noticed that there's no longer a GFCI outlet on the bottom of the timer box.  I removed it, and put the outlet and the light switch in a single box on the left (out of the picture).

[image: ATS box]

This is the automatic transfer switch for the backup generator.  I don't see anything interesting in there that might be tied to the pool pump panel.

Comment: Is there another subpanel or device that is also powered by the main panel breaker?

Comment: Is the feeder to the pool pump panel from the main panel wired in conduit, using cable, or as a mix of the two?

Comment: The main panel is on the inside of my garage wall, and the electric meter is on the outside.  As far as I can tell, the feeder to the pool pump panel comes out of the bottom of the meter box through non-metal conduit into the ground.  I also see non-metal conduit going up through the bottom of the pool pump panel from the ground.  I can't verify that it's running through conduit underground, but I would assume so.

Comment: Is there a junction box somewhere in the middle of this mess @DIYWannabe?

Comment: No, not that I can see.  Perhaps the splice is done inside the meter box.

Comment: Can you post a photo of where the wires exit the main panel? I'm pretty sure that splice is *not* in the meter box -- that's a no-no

Comment: I can't see it.  You can see where the red wires from the 60A breaker to through the back of the main panel, and all I see on the other side of the wall is the meter box with conduit coming out of the bottom.  Now, I do have a backup generator with a transfer switch right next to the meter, but there's no way the feeder to the pool pump panel is coming out of there.

Comment: What size (diameter) is the conduit from the meter box going into the ground?  Pic of the outdoor meter box? Does it have circuit breaker?

Comment: Eye-balling it, looks like 2 inch diameter.  I'm about to post a couple more pictures.

Comment: @DIYWannabe -- I bet the splice is in the transfer switch, indeed -- can you open that up and give us a look?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that tomorrow. It's dark now.

Comment: Oh, I don't think it's the transfer switch because that's new. The sub-panel existed way before that. I don't know why the generator guys would have randomly moved a splice into the transfer switch, but I'll check tomorrow nonetheless.

Comment: Added a picture of the transfer switch.

Comment: AT&T PNI hung off conduit is a straight up codevio: 300.11(b) and *thwack* on AT&T, they of all people should know better.  I would call AT&T and make them fix it.

Comment: I just got rid of AT&T, but they don't remove their old boxes, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, so I agree that the conduit going down out of the meter *must* be the conduit to the pool box, and I am confident that it is conduit all the way, which makes the defective/illegal 120V circuit easy to fix.  I *still* believe that the other H/H/G coming into the pool box goes to the subpanel along the fence, does it lose power when you cut the pool breaker in the main?  Is there any possible conduit routing where that would make sense?

Comment: What's the easy fix?  Should it be relatively straightforward to pull a neutral through the conduit?  Yes, as far as I know, the entire sub-panel loses power when I cut the 60A breaker in the main panel.  I was working on it over the weekend, and never got shocked.  No idea where else the feeder wires could be going.  The only thing out there is the pool equipment.

Comment: @DIYWannabe -- clearly, there's something else going on here.  Is there a terminal block mounted in the bottom right of the generator panel?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You have a 240V-only panel. It does not support neutral.

It provides hot-hot-ground, which is perfectly modern and legal.  It is adequate to power any 240V load.  It cannot power a 120V or 120V-240V split load.

**It is not** a 120/240 split phase panel that has been grandfathered. If it was, it would have *neutral* and not *ground*.

I gather the big flexible black *cordage* goes to a 240V pump.  It appears the wire colors have faded.  It would have been correctly tapped hot-hot-ground, and black, *taped* white and green are legit colors for that connection.

Looking at the updated photos, yes - this is an all-240 setup.  Note that only the black and ...?orange? Wires actually connect to anything.

### Double-taps. NO.

It appears that power visits this panel, then travels onward to another subpanel or point-of-use.

Note how 2 wires are landed on each main lug.  **Not allowed *unless the lug's instructions specifically say double-tapping is OK***. *It's **especially** important to follow instructions when aluminum wire is in use!*  So these should come off, and each pole should go to a 3-tap lug, with a short pigtail (in the larger wire size) to go up to these existing lugs.

Instead, if these wires are **paralleled** from the same supply wires, that is not allowed.  Remove the smaller wire and downbreaker to the ampacity limits of the larger wire.

### That 120V doesn't belong there

This is very typical of 240V-only panels: along comes some clown who wants 120V, and *doesn't care* that it's a 240V-only panel.  (many are *unable to conceptualize* that there *even is such a thing* as a 240V-only panel, they want to install a 120V load, therefore every panel is 120V!)  And so they just "slap in a breaker" and go ahead and **bootleg neutral** off the ground wire.

This work should be torn out on sight.  There should never be current flowing on ground, except when a ground fault is occurring.

Edit: looking at your pix, that's plainly what happened, the 120V GFCI was an afterthought and he just bootlegged neutral *because he didn't know any better*.  Into the trash it goes.

### Dealing with those 120V loads

They never should have been installed in the first place, and need to be replaced.

Lamps are easy: many modern LED fixtures and *most* fluorescent ballasts will work on a range of 110-277 volts.  Wire them up 240 and done.

For pumps and water handling bits, you can get 240V motors or 240V versions of the appliances. (*no 120/240 split phase*).

If all else fails, small 120V loads can be supplied by a 240V/120V isolation transformer.   Using a cheaper "step-up/step-down transformer" is very tricky and I don't recommend it.

Edit: That GFCI+receptacle - gone.  If you have a compelling reason to need a 120V convenience outlet there, you'll need to pull an entirely new 120V circuit from the main panel.  Or alternately, convert this subpanel to split-phase by pulling a neutral from the main panel and replacing this subpanel with a suitable one with a separate neutral and ground bus.

If you continue the light as a 240V light, you'll need to change the white wire to a color.  You are not allowed to tape white wires when the work is in conduit.

### GFCI

I can't quite make what I'm seeing in this panel.  It looks like a 4-*space* GE Qline panel, and you have elected to install their half-width "double stuff" breakers, filling 1.5 of the 4 spaces.

There has to be GFCI protection in here *somewhere*.  It may be at the main panel on the 60A.  This is one thing you shouldn't try to "grandfather".

The problem is GFCIs are bulky breakers.  They don't come in double-stuff.  So you'll need 2 whole spaces (those occupied, plus the empty half-space to the left) just for the 30A pump 2-pole GFCI.

Since it's a 240V-only panel, all breakers must be 2-pole.  That will leave you 2 spaces for **one** more 2-pole GFCI, and that will have to power everything else.  I suppose you could use a 15A or 20A based on which wire sizes you have installed.  As far as outlets, the same rules apply to 240V/15A as 120V/15A; you can have as many outlets as you want shared on the circuit.  You'll have 3600W on a 15A circuit, so power won't be a problem.

Comment: Wow. Incredibly useful information. I'll provide some more info and pictures when I get home this evening to explain the setup further. I would like to remediate this inherited mess as much as possible.

Comment: Added more info.  Please take a look, and let me know what you think.

Comment: Edited.  I'm not worried about the change from red Cu to black Al wire.  That is probably happening wherever the grounds enter the conduit.  Splices are pretty routine.

Comment: So it seems that I have some wacky parallel feeder wiring going on as well as a bootlegged 120V circuit on a 240V-only sub-panel.  Am I correct is saying that there's no way to remediate this without burying a new feeder?

Comment: I need to see the other end of the feeder (transition point) but right now I don't believe it's paralleled, I believe the two smaller wires go off to **yet a third location**.  Why do I believe this? *Because there'd be no reason to parallel grounds*, and yet, there are two.   ----- I also believe you have continuous conduit, why? Because THWN wire was used, and that is not legal for direct burial.

Comment: What's the transition point? I can take a picture.

Comment: You have to ferret those out. Sorry, I'm not there and my drone hasn't the range.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where else those wires could be going.  The pool pump panel is at the back of the property mounted to a concrete fence.  There's nothing else back there.  It's a fairly straight shot from the side of the garage where the main panel is to the pool pump panel (through the backyard).  Nothing in between except grass and my driveway.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking a look at this and providing input.  I've learned several important things: 1) I have a 240V-only sub-panel with an improper 120V circuit which is unsafe.  2) I have weird feeder wiring that doesn't make sense.  3) I'm upset that the home inspector didn't catch any of this.  4) I'm in over my head, and I just need to call in a real electrician to fix all of this.  Thanks @Harper for the detailed analysis.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly tell from the picture, but it could be that they ran 4x 8 gauge THHN aluminum instead of 2x 6 gauge aluminum. It's also possible you have 6 gauge coming in and 8 gauge going out to something else. I would open the main panel and verify what's connected to your 60A breaker.

Comment: Elaborating on: when it is allowed to use multiple parallel wires and how do gauges combine? would make a great answer.

Comment: Interestingly, from the 60A double-pole breaker in the main panel, I see a single black wire and a single red wire. I don't see any of these aluminum wires at all, so I assume that they are spliced somewhere along the way. Does that mean that all four black wires are hot, and the bare wires are neutral? Or are the bare wires ground? I'm also curious to know about running parallel wires and combining guages.

Comment: Mind you, I don't think NEC would like it (nor electrical inspectors), but 2x 8 gauge could carry more than 1x 6 gauge. See [this Electronics.SE on the subject](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110901/will-doubling-thinner-wire-in-lieu-of-thicker-wire-work)

Comment: Paralleling is not allowed at these sizes.  Nor is double tapping lugs.

Comment: I agree code requires 1-0 wire size to parallel NEC 310.10.H.1 for this application. 620.12 allows smaller gauge paralleling but this is not applicable in this case.

Comment: @EdBeal but it's not as simple as "oh, 1/0 I can parallel".  You need special equipment on the supply side.

Comment: @ Harper I just provided the code reference for paralling, as far as using lug doublers if the existing lugs are not rated for 2 wires is really not special.